# Filebeat stop after sometimes while reading yarn logs

Tags: logstash, kibana, hadoop-yarn, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am using filebeat to ship data of yarn logs of hadoop. I am using is filebeat-7.5.1

```yaml
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true

  paths:
    - /root/hadoop/userlogs/**/stderr
    - /root/ingest-logs/ingest.log
    - /root/root-logs/root.log
```

This is configuration mention in the filebeat.yml

> 2020-04-01T16:12:54.871+0530  INFO    kafka/log.go:53 producer/broker/1 maximum request accumulated, waiting for space
>
> 2020-04-01T16:12:54.896+0530  INFO    kafka/log.go:53 producer/broker/1 maximum request accumulated, waiting for space
>
> 2020-04-01T16:12:55.876+0530  INFO    kafka/log.go:53 producer/broker/1 maximum request accumulated, waiting for space
>
> 2020-04-01T16:13:05.950+0530  INFO    beater/filebeat.go:443  Stopping filebeat
>
> 2020-04-01T16:13:05.951+0530  INFO    crawler/crawler.go:139  Stopping Crawler
>
> 2020-04-01T16:13:05.956+0530  INFO    crawler/crawler.go:149  Stopping 1 inputs
>
> 2020-04-01T16:13:05.962+0530  INFO    input/input.go:149  input ticker stopped
>
> 2020-04-01T16:13:05.962+0530  INFO    input/input.go:167  Stopping Input: 4626669614810496825
>
> 2020-04-01T16:13:05.962+0530  INFO    log/harvester.go:272    Reader was closed: /scratch/oba/logs/hadoop/userlogs/application_1582785823666_2626/container_1582785823666_2626_01_000002/stderr. Closing.
> 2020-04-01T16:13:05.962+0530  INFO    log/harvester.go:272    Reader was closed: /root/ingest-logs/ingest.log. Closing.
>
> 2020-04-01T16:13:05.962+0530  INFO    log/harvester.go:272    Reader was closed: /root/ingest-logs/ingest.log. Closing.
>
> 2020-04-01T16:13:05.962+0530  INFO    log/harvester.go:272    Reader was closed: /root/hadoop/userlogs/application_1582785823666_2626/container_1582785823666_2626_01_000001/stderr. Closing.
>
> 2020-04-01T16:13:05.961+0530  INFO    cfgfile/reload.go:229   Dynamic config reloader stopped
>
> 2020-04-01T16:13:05.971+0530  INFO    crawler/crawler.go:165  Crawler stopped
>
> 2020-04-01T16:13:05.971+0530  INFO    registrar/registrar.go:367  Stopping Registrar
>
> 2020-04-01T16:13:05.971+0530  INFO    registrar/registrar.go:293  Ending Registrar

I have a concern about the rolling logs in the yarn and inactive log file. Does it affect the workingof filbeat.
Can you please suggest the changes required in filebeat to keep filebeat alive.

Comment: Is the filebeat **service** really terminating or do you assume that filebeat terminates based on the logs you posted?

Comment: Fileveat terminates itself after some time. I check the process using ps command no other process is running.